# how process SASS and only get 'color' a property and throw away the rest?

Tags: sass

I would like to only get only `color`s properties of a SASS file. (ie. bootstrap.sass).

I would like to import bootstrap

```
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

and throw away everything that is not `color`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
bootstrap.scss
```

only contains imports to other .scss files.

There isn't a way, to my knowledge, that lets you import several .scss files and loop through all of them and only grab color variables

All of bootstrap's colors variables however are stored in

```
./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss
```

if your SASS "structure" (the .scss file you compile to css) looks something like

```
@import _my_variables
@import my_styles
```

You can define all your colors in _my_variables (or copy all of bootstrap's), and use those variables in my_styles